# R - Change default argument of nested function call

Tags: r

I am trying to configure `updateR()` from the package `installr` to use my company's internal CRAN to make upgrading easier for end users.  `updateR()` makes use of another function, `check.for.updates.R()` to determine if a newer version exists.  `check.for.updates.R()` has an argument, `page_with_download_url="http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/base/"` that I want to set to `"http://internal/cran/bin/windows/base/"`.

I used `formals(check.for.updates.R)$page_with_download_url = "http://lnxaws01/cran/bin/windows/base/"` to try and set the default argument.

```
formals(check.for.updates.R)
#>$notify_user
#>[1] TRUE
#>
#>$use_GUI
#>[1] TRUE
#>
#>$page_with_download_url
#>[1] "http://internal/cran/bin/windows/base/"
#>
#>$pat
#>[1] "R-[0-9.]+-win"
```

So, that seems to have worked.  Check that it's actually working:

```
check.for.updates.R(use.GUI=F)
#>No need to update. You are using the latest R version: 
 R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)[1] FALSE
```

Note - at the time of posting this, R 3.2.0 has just been released, our internal CRAN is still running 3.1.3 so this is the correct response.

However, `updateR()` continues to check the RStudio CRAN and ends up thinking there's a new package available.

With the `Defaults` package removed from CRAN (and maybe it wouldn't have helped anyway) how can I change the default argument value for a function nested inside another function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because when you "modify" `check.for.updates.R`, you are not really modifying it.  Instead, you are creating a copy that is assigned to the global environment that masks the original copy.  So if you run the function, it will look like it is doing what you expect.  But, if you run `updateR` it will instead look in its namespace environment, which is where the *original* unchanged function lives.

Since `updateR` does not expose the required `check.for.updates.R` argument, you can instead `trace` `check.for.updates.R`:

```
trace(
  installr::check.for.updates.R, 
  quote(page_with_download_url <- "http://internal/cran/bin/windows/base/")
)
```

This will make that line of code the first line run in `check.for.updates.R`.  Note we are completely overriding the argument, not just changing the default, but it seems this will work for you.